# Изменение состояния у компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

По нажатию на чекбокс должна вызываться функция из глобального компонента, а в функцию должен передаваться id строки на которую нажал

Функция должна сначала копировать все данные, потом мапом проходиться по всем строчкам и у записи у которой id равно id текущей записи, поменять item.checked = !item.checked на противоположное значение

Хотелось бы понять как это сделать, хотя бы пример

Comment: вот после тем которые надо прочесть если не получится кинь не рабочий код, и дай знать

Answer (score 0):

1.По нажатию на чекбокс должна вызываться функция из глобального компонента( прочитай про context в реакт)

1. в функцию должен передаваться id строки на которую нажал( f(id) )
2. Функция должна сначала копировать все данные, потом мапом проходиться по всем строчкам (map и так возвращает копию)
3. и у записи у которой id равно id текущей записи, поменять item.checked = !item.checked на противоположное значение (массивы и обекты)
4. и еше надо про useState и useReducer(не обязательно но желательно) прочитать